# O que é necessário para se criar um sistema de autenticação (login/senha/sessão) em PHP? Que pontos importantes eu devo me preocupar?

Tags: php, session, criptografia

Estou querendo criar um site com meu próprio sistema de autenticação, sem utilizar nada pronto.

Gostaria de saber quais as etapas para a criação desse sistema, na ordem.

Se existe uma convenção de melhores práticas e que pontos eu não posso esquecer de levar em consideração na hora da criação para que seja seguro.

Comment: Ok. Votei para encerrar.

Comment: Exclui minha resposta. Não conseguiria dar uma boa resposta, então melhor nem dar. E agora vi também que é uma possível duplicata.

Answer (score 2):

Um comando que é muito importante você usar é o **addslashes** na hora de receber os dados de login, porque ele evita que  você seja vitima de sql inject porque ele coloca uma `\` antes de cada aspa assim ajudando a te proteger do sql inject por exemplo:

```
$email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
$senha = addslashes($_POST['senha']);
```

informações detalhadas [addslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.addslashes.php)

Por exemplo se você não usar o addslashes o usuário pode digitar no campo senha e te enviar isso **' or '1'='1**  aí quando você for fazer sua query ficara mais ou menos assim

```
SELECT email,senha FROM usuarios WHERE email='qualquer coisa' senha='' or '1'='1'
```

E assim ele conseguira acessar sua sessão, mas com o addslashes você está seguro enquanto a isto

Exemplo usando addslashes:

```
SELECT email,senha FROM usuarios WHERE email='qualquer coisa' senha='\' or \'1\'=\'1'
```

Isso fara com que de erro na query mas ele não acessara suas informações

Comment: @Joao Paulo dá uma olha nessa aqui